# Access my locally hosted website from another computer outside my network without a domain name

Tags: iis, web-hosting

I want to access my locally hosted website (Windows 10) from another computer outside my network. I don’t own a domain. Is it possible to do this using an IP address? If so, what steps should I take? I have tried IIS Manager but could not work out how to do what I want.

Comment: What is `host name` exactly, in this case? Your server's name? Your server's IP address? Your router's IP address? Your DNS domain name?

Comment: The host name I am using is photos222.com but that is arbitrary as I do not own a domain name. If I leave the host name blank I can see the website in my browser with the address localhost.port. I do not know the server name unless it is the name of my computer. I do not know my server’s IP address. Does IIS manager have an IP address? I do not have a domain so no DNS domain name. My router’s ip address is 192.168.0.1.

Comment: This the process I am using: 
1. Start page/ connect to localhost
2. Sites/ add website
3. Site name: photos222.com
4. physical path
5. IP address: all unassigned
6. Host name – if blank I can see the website in my browser. If I use photos222.com I cannot.

Comment: How do you expect the browser to know where photos222.com *is*, if you don't own that name (and haven't pointed it to the server's address)?

Comment: At this stage I am just trying to access my website from another computer outside my network. I intend to add a domain name later. Can I do this using an IP address, that is a string of numbers, instead of a domain name?

Comment: Ah, right, so you're entering the domain name only in IIS, not in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I am clicking Browse Website in the right pane of IIS manager.

Comment: Have you added the firewall rule also on windows firewall?

Comment: Yes, I added a port inbound rule. Also, I am not particularly attached to using IIS manager. If anybody can recommend any way to allow me to view my website from a computer outside my network without using a domain name I would be grateful.

Comment: You can’t just use something like photos222.com without registering it and setting up DNS for it. You also have to forward the port within your own network so the server is accessible outside of your network. Instead of dozens of comments containing fragments of information you should edit your question

Comment: hm, would a hosts file entry work here on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few services that allow you to tunnel a localhost port out ot the internet.

ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) or Cloudflare Tunnels (https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-networks/do-more-with-tunnels/trycloudflare/), to name a few.

For e.g. with a Cloudflare tunnel:

1. Install Cloudflared from https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-networks/downloads/
2. Run `cloudflared tunnel --url http://localhost:<port>` and it'll give you a host you can go to to view your site

Bear in mind that both of those solutions will put your site on the public internet, so don't put anything up (read: secrets, api keys etc) that you don't want someone to stumble on.

Comment: As far as I can see Cloudflared requires a domain name. I looked into open source alternatives to Ngrok and found Tunnelmole. That worked and I was able to view my site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hosting a website with just an IP address is entirely possible. However, you cannot use name-based virtual hosting with this. As such, you *must not* add a host name in the IIS Bindings dialog.

You can change the bindings at any time if you later decide to actually have a domain.

---

You also need appropriate firewall and port forwarding rules. Keep in mind that some ISPs block some or all incoming connections anyway. Some ISPs also use carrier-grade NAT, which makes it impossible for you to host a service.

Comment: What IP address should I use to do this? At the moment I have it working on localhost:port

Comment: Use the IP address for what? The IIS binding? Or in the browser, to access the site from your local intranet? Or in the browser, to access the site from outside your local network (“on the internet”)?

Comment: In the browser, to access the site from outside my local network. Does it take the form MyPrivateIPAddress:port?

Comment: Generally yes, but you need your public IP address. You can [ask DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+is+my+ip&ia=answer). If you forwarded port 80, you do not need the port, because that’s the default HTTP port.